# Sencha Touch: How to read certain record from the store?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, store

I have an application that has 3 level of data depth:

- list of presentations
- presentation detail
- presentation slides

Right now when user came to the app he's presented with list loaded from JSONP store. He click on one item and the callback function receives the record. It pushes it into new view - the detail and displays it. User can disclose presentation slides from there - data record is passed from detail again.

Problem is when user refreshes the page or came from URL. If he came to url like /presentations/slides/1, he wants to see the slides for presentation id:1. Problem is that as long as he wasn't at the list, data was not loaded and because it was not loaded, it was not passed to the detail and the detail didn't pass it along to the slides view. So I have no data.

But I still have the ID! Comming from the PHP's Zend Framework, I would call something like: `this.store.find(1)`, but I can't find any way to do this.

How do I load something from the store based on it's `record.data.id`?

To add more, `store.load()` seems to work asyncronously, so when I do:

```
store.load();
store.each(function(rec){console.log(rec);});
```

It wouldn't work with JSONP store, because the data is not loaded yet. But when I use Chrome Debuger and pause the execution to let the data load, it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the load is asyncronously so all you have to do is use the callback function of the store. You can find an example here [How to get data from extjs 4 store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8367074/861874)

Comment: yes, the problem is: how to delay the running action? I'm in the dispatch process and if I use the callback it will fail further down the code, where is assumes it has the record.

Comment: And still I'm unable to receive the one record from the store :(

Comment: well you either move all code depending on the record in the callback function, or either set an listener on the load of the store and you can add the code there knowing that the store is loaded.

Comment: And loading one exact item from the store?

Comment: on the callback or on the function fired by load event , you can use var rec = store.findRecord('id',idOfRecYouWant)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for.

Comment: ay... once again. Not what I ''ve been looking for. I need the store to contact the server and get the item. It doesn't have to be loaded (can be on page 25 for ex.). I have so much content, that I can't load the whole content at once.