# why I can't get JSON from server in ExtJs4?

Tags: ajax, django, extjs, extjs4

I wanna get JSON from the server.And here is the django server view function:

```
def showChart(request):
    data = [{"id":1, "name":"Tom", "email":"a@a.com"}, {"id":2, "name":"Bosh", "email":"c@c.com"}]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json");
```

Obviously, showChart() will return a json.

My frontend extjs4 code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.define('ProductionInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['email', 'id', 'name']
});

var store_new = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ProductionInfo',
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url : 'http://localhost:8000/production_data',
      reader: {
          type: 'json'
      }
    }
});

store_new.load();
alert(store_new.getCount());
```

});

But the alert dialog shows '0', while the right answer is '2'. So why I can't get JSON from server? (I can get the right JSON through a GET request in Chorme and Firefox)

Comment: The store is loaded asynchronously, so it is still loading while you call the `getCount` method (and thus get return value of 0). You need to add a listener to the `load` event (of the store) if you want to execute some logic that takes place after loading is done.

Comment: Tom is correct the store load is asynchronous, maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367074/how-to-get-data-from-extjs-4-store/8376810#8376810

Comment: Thank you, Tom and nscrob! "the store load is asynchronous" is the key. So I put 'alert(store_new.getCount());' in  the load event (of the store), it returns 2 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You could check my sample: https://github.com/lucassus/extjs4-account-manager
It's rails application but json mechanism is very similar.

Basically you have to define a model with valid `proxy`: https://github.com/lucassus/extjs4-account-manager/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/model/User.js
and a store which will have `model` attribute:  https://github.com/lucassus/extjs4-account-manager/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/store/Users.js

Comment: When I run my extjs4 code, the server can detect the Ext's ajax request. My code is based on the extjs4 official documentation.